# How to stop/disable internet access with Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to stop internet access via Java?  I want to make a program for my own use to disconnect from the internet, through any means necessary.  Can Java intercept internet requests, or disconnect from wifi?

If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Java API for that. 
You can use either JNI or an external program for this task.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  In 3 minutes I'll be able to check this answer.  Is it possible to do this via batch?  I really need a way to do this to be able to successfully run a certain application.

Comment: You can execute a script file with the Process class (and create it with ProcessBuilder). In Windows you may have to use "cmd /c batchfile", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, sort of.

You can create a "proxy" type application in Java, that acts as a router. So, for example, it would listen on port 9000 for any requests, and, depending on what is in that request, forward it and the subsequent response, to the original application.  This of course assumes you can tweak the client application to use localhost:9000 as the access point.

Take a look at Rabbit http://www.khelekore.org/rabbit/index.shtml for an example of how to create a proxy server in Java.